# SVM Response Array Size Error

Tags: opencv, svm

I used some sort of SVM:

```
#include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"
#include "opencv2/features2d/features2d.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/nonfree/features2d.hpp"
#include "opencv2/nonfree/nonfree.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/ml/ml.hpp>

using namespace cv;

int main()
{
    // Data for visual representation
    int width = 512, height = 512;
    Mat image = Mat::zeros(height, width, CV_8UC3);

    //Load Data and Labels from csv files
    CvMLData mlData;
    mlData.read_csv("/home/rahim/workspace/svm/DataTrain1-svm.csv");
    const CvMat* tmpDataTr = mlData.get_values();
    cv::Mat DataTrt(tmpDataTr, true);
    tmpDataTr->CvMat::~CvMat();
    cout << "M = "<< DataTrt << " "  << DataTrt << endl << endl;
    Mat DataTr = DataTrt.t();

    mlData.read_csv("/home/rahim/workspace/svm/LabelTrain1-svm.csv");
    const CvMat* tmpLabelTr = mlData.get_values();
    cv::Mat LabelTrt(tmpLabelTr, true);
    tmpLabelTr->CvMat::~CvMat();
    cout << "M = "<< LabelTrt << " "  << LabelTrt << endl << endl;
    Mat LabelTr = LabelTrt.t();
    cout << "Data size = " << DataTr.size() << endl;
    cout << "labels size = " << LabelTr.size() << endl;

    // Set up SVM's parameters
    CvSVMParams params;
    params.svm_type    = CvSVM::C_SVC;
    params.kernel_type = CvSVM::LINEAR;
    params.term_crit   = cvTermCriteria(CV_TERMCRIT_ITER, 100, 1e-6);

    // Train the SVM
    CvSVM SVM;
    //SVM.train(trainingData, traininglabels, Mat(), Mat(), params);
    SVM.train(DataTr, LabelTr, Mat(), Mat(), params);
    Vec3b green(0,255,0), blue (255,0,0);
    // Show the decision regions given by the SVM
    for (int i = 0; i < image.rows; ++i)
        for (int j = 0; j < image.cols; ++j)
        {
            Mat sampleMat = (Mat_<float>(1,2) << j,i);
            float response = SVM.predict(sampleMat);

            if (response == 1)
                image.at<Vec3b>(i,j)  = green;
            else if (response == -1)
                 image.at<Vec3b>(i,j)  = blue;
        }

    // Show the training data
    int thickness = -1;
    int lineType = 8;
    circle( image, Point(501,  10), 5, Scalar(  0,   0,   0), thickness, lineType);
    circle( image, Point(255,  10), 5, Scalar(255, 255, 255), thickness, lineType);
    circle( image, Point(501, 255), 5, Scalar(255, 255, 255), thickness, lineType);
    circle( image, Point( 10, 501), 5, Scalar(255, 255, 255), thickness, lineType);

    // Show support vectors
    thickness = 2;
    lineType  = 8;
    int c     = SVM.get_support_vector_count();

    for (int i = 0; i < c; ++i)
    {
        const float* v = SVM.get_support_vector(i);
        circle( image,  Point( (int) v[0], (int) v[1]),   6,  Scalar(128, 128, 128), thickness, lineType);
    }

    imwrite("result.png", image);        // save the image

    imshow("SVM Simple Example", image); // show it to the user
    waitKey(0);

}
```

but I got the following error :
guments do not match (Response array must contain as many elements as the total number of samples) in cvPreprocessCategoricalResponses

the output for DataTr.size() and LabelTr.size() are [1800*9] and [1800*1] respectively

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you have 1800 samples and 9 variables.

According to [OpenCV documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/ml/doc/support_vector_machines.html#cvsvm-train) `CvSVM::train` only supports data which contains samples in rows. So you don't need transposing your train data on line:

```
Mat DataTr = DataTrt.t();
```

You also don't need to transpose label data. But it's not so critical, since label data only must contain number of elements equal to number of samples. It does not matter row-wise or column-wise.